# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException when add @PreAuthorize annotation

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-security, requestfactory

I'm trying to perform integration of my GWT application and Spring Security. And when I add `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` annotation to the method of my DAO class following exception appears:

> No unique bean of type [server.dao.ElementServiceDAO] is defined:
>   expected single bean but found 0

DaoServiceLocator can't find DAO bean, but in debug mode I see elementServiceDAO bean in ApplicationContext instance.

My DAO class looks like this:

```
@Service
public class ElementServiceDAO extends EntityDAO {

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Layer getFullRenderingTopology() {
...
}

}
```

DAO service locator's code:

```
public class DaoServiceLocator implements ServiceLocator {

@Override
public Object getInstance(final Class<?> clazz) {
    try {
        final HttpServletRequest request = RequestFactoryServlet
                .getThreadLocalRequest();

        final ServletContext servletContext = request.getSession()
                .getServletContext();

        final ApplicationContext context = WebApplicationContextUtils
                .getWebApplicationContext(servletContext);

        return context.getBean(clazz);
    } catch (final Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}
```

applicationContext-security.xml:

```
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <user-service>
            <user name="operator" password="operator" authorities="ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN" />
            <user name="guest" password="guest" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>

<global-method-security pre-post-annotations="enabled" />
```

Please give me any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ElementServiceDAO` implements an interface (in your case - transitively via `EntityDAO`), Spring by default creates an interface-based proxy to apply security aspects. So, `elementServiceDAO` in your application context is a proxy that isn't instance of `ElementServiceDAO`, therefore it cannot be retrieved by type.

You either need to

- force creation of target-class-based proxies as follows

  ```
  <global-method-security 
      pre-post-annotations="enabled" proxy-target-class = "true" />
  ```
- or create a business interface for `ElementServiceDAO` and use that interface instead of implementation class.

**See also:**

- [7.6 Proxying mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your first assumption doesn't work for me, but second is what I'm looking for!